# White Space around List View Items

Tags: android, listview, height, listitem

I am having a list view and its list items are generated using Array List and it creates unecessary white space which occupies much space.

How do I remove it from the list items?

Here is my list view:

```
<ListView
   android:id="@+id/list"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="0dp" android:layout_weight="1"
   android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
   android:dividerHeight="10.0sp"/>
```

And my list items:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <ImageView 
        android:id="@+id/photo"
        android:layout_width="140dip"
        android:layout_height="140dip"
        android:paddingRight="15dp"
        android:paddingLeft="15dp"/>
    <TextView android:id="@+id/name"
        android:textSize="14sp" 
        android:textStyle="bold" 
        android:textColor="#000000" 
        android:paddingTop="30dp" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/photo"/>
    <TextView android:id="@+id/itemDescription"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/name"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/photo"/>
    <TextView android:id="@+id/price" 
        android:textSize="19sp" 
        android:textStyle="bold" 
        android:textColor="#32cd32" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/itemDescription"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/photo"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: where is the white space? Do you have any screenshot?

Comment: Show a picture with these white spaces you're talking about.

Comment: @RenanBandeira and Piotr Chojnacki- Sorry :) I thought I have added it..Added it now please check

Answer (score 0):

just remove  android:dividerHeight="10.0sp" from xml or make it 1sp or smaller

this may also the problem:
android:layout_height="0dp" android:layout_weight="1"

why not giving height as "wrap_content" ? no need to android:layout_weight="1" i think

Comment: @Kalpesh-Just now tried by removing them but still I get the space

Comment: also getting this unnecessory space before first list item and after last list item of listview ?

Answer (score 0):

use height `wrap-content` for relativelayout in listitems.xml

```
<RelativeLayout
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content">

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this for your row, change image and color to yours ..(Use linear)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#123133" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/photo"
        android:layout_width="140dip"
        android:layout_height="140dip"
        android:paddingLeft="15dp"
        android:paddingRight="15dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" 
        android:gravity="center">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="AAAAASDKDJ"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/itemDescription"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="AAAAASDKDJ" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/price"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="AAAAASDKDJ"
            android:textColor="#32cd32"
            android:textSize="19sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

The property `android:dividerHeight="10.0sp"` is making all the extra space. Put something lower like `3sp` or `5sp`.